# How to get dropdown's value and text both in form.serialize?

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my project I want the serialize data of the form, but for the dropdowns it gives the values only not a text of that selected value of drop down.

```
<select name='attend'>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Question</option>
    <option value="2">Attending</option>
    <option value="3">not-attending</option>
</select>
```

Here it gives attend = 1. I also want the text of that selected option that is "Question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serialize()` will only retrieve the `name` and `value` properties from an element.

To do what you require you can use `serialize()` as normal, then append the selected option text to it:

```js
var data = $('form').serialize() + '&attendText=' + $('select option:selected').text();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name='attend'>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Question</option>
    <option value="2">Attending</option>
    <option value="3">not-attending</option>
</select>
</form>
```

If you wanted to use `serializeArray()` you would need to `push()` the data to the resulting object, like this:

```js
var data = $('form').serializeArray();
data.push({ 
  name: 'attendText',
  value: $('select option:selected').text() 
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name='attend'>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Question</option>
    <option value="2">Attending</option>
    <option value="3">not-attending</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: but i am using serializeArray() and when i am trying to concate the value of the dropdown in that it shows like [object Object]&attendText=Commercial in console means it lost other data?

Comment: `serializeArray()` returns an array, not a string like `serialize()`. In that case you'd need to use `push()` to add the new object with the required data

Comment: With which format I have to concat that selected text to serializedArray?

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan